# how to insert two values manually into table by using code

Tags: c#, linq

I am having table named **ROLES**. I want to insert two values manually to show in dropdown, *"--Any--"* and *"--select roles--"*. I have already inserted *"--select roles--"*. But i don't know how to insert another "--Any--"  value here.

**My code here**

```
return new[] { new Role { Id = 0, Name = "--Select Roles--" } }.Concat(
            (from role in _db.Roles
             where role.FunctionId == functionId
             orderby role.Name ascending
             select role)).ToList();
```

I am really stuck here. Please help me to come out this issue..

Comment: I don't think you should treat --select roles-- as role entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to treat these values as role entities:

```
var result = new List<Role> {
   new Role { Id = 0, Name = "--Select Roles--" },
   new Role { Id = -1, Name = "--Any--" }
};

var roles = from role in _db.Roles
            where role.FunctionId == functionId
            orderby role.Name ascending
            select role;

result.AddRange(roles);

return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list=new[] { new Role { Id = 0, Name = "--Select Roles--" } }.Concat(
            (from role in _db.Roles
             where role.FunctionId == functionId
             orderby role.Name ascending
             select role)).ToList();

list.Insert(0,new Role { Id = -1, Name = "--Any--" });
retrun list;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 var returnList=from role in _db.Roles
                 where role.FunctionId == functionId
                 orderby role.Name ascending
                 select role)).ToList();



 return returnList.InsertRange(0,new List<Role>(){
                           new Role { Id = 0, Name = "--Select Roles--" },
                           new Role { Id = -1, Name = "--Any--" } 

                               })
```